# Ms-Access - IF checkbox = true THEN

Tags: ms-access, vba

How would i make it so that when 4 check boxs are all ticked (true) then the button may then be pressed to save the record.

The four checkbox s are called "chk1, chk2 chk3, chk4" 
button is called "button"

i presume that it would something along the lines of "If Chk1, chk2, chk3, ck4 = True Then Button = visible?"

and then if the check boxes are not true then the button is not able to be pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a function that checks the checkboxes and sets the button state accordingly...

```
Function CheckMyButton()
    Me.MyButton.Enabled = (Me.chk1 And Me.chk2 And Me.chk3 And Me.chk4)
    ' If you want to be more verbose, do
    ' (Me.chk1.Value=True And Me.chk2.Value=True And ...
End Function
```

... and call this function from the `After Update` event of all checkboxes.
**Edit** and probably in the `Form_Current` event too, if it's a bound form.

You can directly use

```
=CheckMyButton()
```

in the event property, no need for 4 event procedures.

Comment: A compile error occurs (Expected:Line number or label or statement or end statement

Comment: Please post a new question with your exact code. @MattH